# How do I pass an array of class objects to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I'm still new to C++ and I am stuck :( how do I pass an array of class objects to a function?
I thought you had to declare the array type and name in the function prototype, hence I wrote “int _displayinfo(class details user[]);” and in the function call you had to write the array name and number of the arrays [].

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int _input();
int _displayinfo(class details user[]);

class details
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
};

int _input()
{
    class details user[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name:";
        cin >> user[i].name;
        cout << "Enter age:";
        cin >> user[i].age;
    }
    return 0;
}

int _displayinfo(details user[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "User " << i << user[i].name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _input();
    _displayinfo(details user[]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this give you a compilation error? If so, what is it?

Comment: In C++, you have lots of library objects you can use as containers: e.g. `std::vector`, `std::set`. They are template-based though so can take a while to get used to. Well worth taking the time to understand them though.

Comment: Most of your problems have nothing to do with the array contents. Start with arrays of primitive types and understand those first.

Comment: Why do your function names start with a `_`?

Comment: No, don't start with arrays at all. There are enough problems with the code before you even start talking arrays. Start with a single user. Better yet, to exclude yet another factor, start with a single string. Make one function read it, and another function write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is too long to comment in English your bad code so it will be better if I will simply rewrite it. I do not check that input is valid. ( WIthout testing )

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct details
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

void input( details user[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the name: ";
        std::cin >> user[i].name;
        std::cout << "Enter age: ";
        std::cin >> user[i].age;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void displayinfo( const details user[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "User " << i << ": " << user[i].name 
                  << " is " << user[i].age << " years old." << std::endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    details user[N];

    input( user, N );
    displayinfo( user, N );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this might be your problem

```
_input();
_displayinfo(details user[]);
```

The user array does not exist at this point. If it does, you would only pass the name, e.g.

```
_displayinfo(user);
```

Comment: Well more to the point that function call is simply invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is:

```
int _displayinfo(const details* user, int size)
```

as `int _displayinfo(details user[])` decays to `int _displayinfo(details* user)`

An other way is to write:

```
int _displayinfo(const details (&user)[3])
```

An other way is to use `std::vector<details>` or `std::array<details, 3>`

and so write:

```
int _displayinfo(const std::vector<details>& user)
int _displayinfo(const std::array<details, 3>& user)
```

Note: I add `const` as you don't modify array inside `_displayinfo`.